# This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Just trying to get the lowdown on "This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose"

I have version 3.8.16:

```
 $ npm list mongoose
 myapp@0.0.1 /Users/me/dev/myapp/src
 └── mongoose@3.8.16
```

This page says that *odd* versions are unstable and *even* versions are stable:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58318358173/mongoose-3-7-0-unstable-released

So is it a mistake that version 3.8.16 has "This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose" in

```
 myapp/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js?
```

Comment: That message only gets generated if the package.json file indicates it should, which only occurs in odd versions.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK.  Your comment made me look a little closer.  I'm embarrassed that I didn't noticed what that message was wrapped in:`if (pkg.publishConfig && 'unstable' == pkg.publishConfig.tag) {
  if (!process.env.MONGOOSE_DISABLE_STABILITY_WARNING) {`

Answer (score 1):

Look at what that comment is wrapped in--it won't always be printed, which was your assumption:

`if (pkg.publishConfig && 'unstable' == pkg.publishConfig.tag) {
  if (!process.env.MONGOOSE_DISABLE_STABILITY_WARNING) {`